# Get child hierarchy for a subset of users

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a customer table where there can be a hierarchy of parent-child records.
The customer table has a structure like,

```
customer { 
    id integer,
    user_id integer,
    parent_id integer
}
```

Given an user_id I know how to fetch all child users in hierachy that belong to the given user_id. For example for user_id value of 100,

```
WITH RECURSIVE subordinates AS (
SELECT c1.* 
FROM customer c1 
WHERE c1.user_id = 100 
UNION 
SELECT c2.* 
FROM customer c2 
INNER JOIN subordinates s 
ON s.id = c2.parent_id)
 
SELECT * FROM subordinates;
```

But I would like to restrict the output of above query to a subset of users. So the first argument to the above query will be a parent user_id (let's call it `parent_user`) and the second argument will be a list of user_id (let's call it `child_users`).

What I would like to do is,

1. Iterate over `child_users`
2. Check if `child_user` in `child_users` is a child of `parent_user`
3. If yes, fetch entire child hierachy of `child_user`

Can above 3 steps be achieved in a single sql query. Plese suggest.

**EDIT**

The sample table data can be,

```
id user_id  parent_id
-----------------------
1   100      null
2   101      100
3   102      101
4   103      102
5   104      100
6   105      null
```

So given above data in the table, for input values of `parent_user = 100` and `child_users = [101, 105]` I am expetcting to retrieve following output,

```
id user_id  parent_id
-----------------------
2   101      100
3   102      101
4   103      102
```

The record with `id = 5` should't be part of the output even though it has `parent_id = 100` since `user_id 104` is not in the `child_users` list.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana FYI Added sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the answers below and let me know if that works

```
declare @Customer  table ( Id int,userID int,parentID int)

insert @Customer (Id, userID, parentID)

select 1,100,null union all <br/>
select 1,101,100 union all <br/>
select 1,102,101 union all <br/>
select 1,103,102 union all <br/>
select 1,104,100 union all <br/>
select 1,105,null  <br/>

;with cte_emp as  <br/>
(  <br/>
select ID,userID,parentID 
from @Customer 
where  parentID=100 and userID in (101,105) <br/>
union all <br/>
select e.ID,e.userID,e.parentID
from @Customer e join cte_emp cte
on cte.userid=e.parentID <br/>
) <br/>

select * from cte_emp <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you want to filter on the immediate parent of the starting node. You can just put that condition in the anchor of the CTE:

```
with recursive subordinates as (
    select c.* 
    from customer
    where user_id = any($1) and parent_id = $2
    union all
    select c.* 
    from customer c
    inner join subordinates s on s.id = c.parent_id
)
select * from subordinates;
```

Note that I changed the query to accept to input parameters:

- `$1` is an array of child ids
- `$2` is the id of the parent that is used to filter

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GMB. I would like to retrieve entire hierarchy of children for the every entry in child_users list if that entry/user_id is a child of parent_user. I have added some sample data and the desired output to the question. I tried running your query against the sample data but it produced no output.